# Getting the source address of an incoming socket connection

Tags: c, sockets, ip

I have a server with a incoming socket from a client.
I need the get the IP address of the remote client.
Tried searching google for `in_addr` but it's a bit troublesome.
Any suggestions?

Comment: <a href="http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpeername"><code>man getpeername</code></a>

Comment: in_addr is IPv4-specific, anyway

Comment: see inet_ntoa(..) function in linux.. 'man inet_ntoa' . it is easier than inet_ntop in my opinion and needs including arpa/inet.h. here is an example: http://www.binarytides.com/programming-udp-sockets-c-linux/

Answer (score 39):

You need the [`getpeername` function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpeername.2.html):

```
// assume s is a connected socket

socklen_t len;
struct sockaddr_storage addr;
char ipstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
int port;

len = sizeof addr;
getpeername(s, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &len);

// deal with both IPv4 and IPv6:
if (addr.ss_family == AF_INET) {
    struct sockaddr_in *s = (struct sockaddr_in *)&addr;
    port = ntohs(s->sin_port);
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &s->sin_addr, ipstr, sizeof ipstr);
} else { // AF_INET6
    struct sockaddr_in6 *s = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)&addr;
    port = ntohs(s->sin6_port);
    inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &s->sin6_addr, ipstr, sizeof ipstr);
}

printf("Peer IP address: %s\n", ipstr);
```

Comment: +1. However don't we have to free any memory for this?

Comment: I notice the `struct sockaddr_in *s` shadows the socket `s` in the outer scope. Having a shadowed variable isn't ideal.

Comment: is there a way to get the socketDescriptor from the address

Comment: @RecolicKeghart try wayback machine :)

Comment: @brk It works! Please use [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160310061801/http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/getpeernameman.html) if you're suffering from 404 too.

Answer (score 21):

Assuming you're using `accept()` to accept incoming socket connections, `getpeername()` isn't needed. The address information is available via the 2nd and 3rd parameters of the `accept()` call.

Here is Eli's answer modified to do it without `getpeername()`:

```
int client_socket_fd;
socklen_t len;
struct sockaddr_storage addr;
char ipstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
int port;

len = sizeof addr;
client_socket_fd = accept(server_socket_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &len);

// deal with both IPv4 and IPv6:
if (addr.ss_family == AF_INET) {
    struct sockaddr_in *s = (struct sockaddr_in *)&addr;
    port = ntohs(s->sin_port);
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &s->sin_addr, ipstr, sizeof ipstr);
} else { // AF_INET6
    struct sockaddr_in6 *s = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)&addr;
    port = ntohs(s->sin6_port);
    inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &s->sin6_addr, ipstr, sizeof ipstr);
}

printf("Peer IP address: %s\n", ipstr);
```

Comment: +1 for directly using `accept()`. However don't we have to free any memory for this?

Comment: @iammilind: I don't think any memory needs to be freed—I can't see any dynamic allocations being done. It's all done with statically allocated variables.

Answer (score 2):

Since you say it is an incoming connection from a client, as an alternative to `getpeername` you can just save the address that was returned by the `accept()` call, in the second and third parameters.