# socket: showing ip and hostname of the client

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, server

I have TCP server and client programs.  My client is sending messages to the server, which is echoing the messages back to the client.

In my server, I'd like to print what I received, but before that I'd like to show the IP and hostname of the client.  How would I do that?

I tried some code, but that doesn't seem to be working, the IP is shown as `"0.0.0.0"`.  I had the same program in UDP and it was working fine.

Also, how do I print the hostname?  Client/Server is on the same machine.

Here is the code of my server (interesting part is at the end):

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int listenSocket, status, socketClient;
  unsigned short int msgLength;
  struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo;
  struct sockaddr_in clientAddress;
  socklen_t clientAddressLength = sizeof clientAddress;
  char msg[101]; //Chaque message fait 100 caractères ma

  if ((listenSocket = socket(servinfo->ai_family, servinfo->ai_socktype,
                             servinfo->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
    perror("socket:");
    return 4;


  if (listen(listenSocket, 5) != 0) {
    printf("Erreur de listen : %s", strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
  }

  int sizeOfSockAddr = sizeof(clientAddress);
  socketClient= accept(listenSocket, NULL, NULL);
  if (socketClient < 0) {
    printf("error accept: %s\n",strerror(errno));
    return 6;
  }

  // Libération de la mémoire occupée par les enregistrements
  freeaddrinfo(servinfo);

  printf("Attente de requête du client sur le port %s\n", argv[1]);

  while (1) {

    // Mise à zéro du tampon de façon à connaître le délimiteur de fin de chaîne.
    memset(msg, 0, sizeof msg);
    if (recv(socketClient, msg, sizeof msg, 0) == -1) {
      perror("recv:");
      close(listenSocket);
      close(listenSocket);
      return 7;
    }

    msgLength = strlen(msg);
    if (msgLength > 0) {
      printf(">>  from %s", inet_ntoa(clientAddress.sin_addr));


      printf(":%hu\n", ntohs(clientAddress.sin_port));


      printf("  Message reçu : %s\n", msg);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064636/getting-the-source-address-of-an-incoming-socket-connection

Comment: 2 things wrong here `   printf(">>  from %s", inet_ntoa(clientAddress.sin_addr));` you have not done anything with clientAddress, sin_addr is not a string

Comment: yes it's fine now, i corrected it ! I'm now wondering how to print the hostname after the getnameinfo function

Comment: getnameinfo should have loaded the name into a string for you, printf it

Answer (score 2):

You have a `clientAddress` variable to hold the client's IP and port, and you are even printing that out, but you are not actually populating it with any meaningful data.

`accept()` can optionally fill that variable for you:

```
accept(listenSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&clientAddress, &clientAddressLength);
```

Or, you can use `getpeername()` instead:

```
getpeername(socketClient, (struct sockaddr *)&clientAddress, &clientAddressLength);
```

As for getting the client's hostname, you can pass the `clientAddress` (after it has been populated) to `getnameinfo()`:

```
char hostname[NI_MAXHOST] = {};
getnameinfo((struct sockaddr *)&clientAddress, clientAddressLength, hostname, sizeof(hostname), NULL, 0, 0);
// use hostname as needed...
```

On a side note:

- when using `getaddrinfo()` to create listening sockets, you should include the `AI_PASSIVE` flag in the `hints.ai_flags` field.
- since you are using `getaddrinfo()` to handle IPv4, with the potential of easily updating it to support IPv6 later on, you should consider switching from `inet_ntoa()` to either `inet_ntop()` or `getnameinfo(NI_NUMERICHOST)` instead when printing the client's IP.  `inet_ntoa()` only supports IPv4, but the others support both IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i now have exactly what I wanted ! :)